# Automatical timezone

Tags: javascript

I want to set a date to the correct timezone. This is my code:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setDate(now.getDate() + (3 + (7 - now.getDay())) % 7)
now.setHours(15, 0, 0);
```

How can I make it to automatically check my timezone and set the time? I want to set the UTC time to 15. And also, how can I test it to be sure that it works?

Comment: What is your definition of *the correct timezone*?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-javascript-date-to-a-particular-timezone

Comment: @ScottMarcus 15:00 UTC

Comment: @Octopus But how can I do it when I set the date by setDate() and setHours()?

Comment: You don't need to. Just create the date with the correct time zone and then any changes you make to portions of the date remain relative to the time zone you've set.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've done it like this: now.toLocaleString("en-US", {localeMatcher: "best fit"}); But how can I test it?

Comment: So, if you were to make changes to the hour or minute, for example, as long as you get the result with that same `toLocaleString()`, you'll have the correct time.